# Alternative of PuppeteerSharp and Selenium to scrape web page after login in C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, web-scraping

I have tried both PuppeteerSharp and Selenium to scrape the webpage after login and redirect to the page and scrape the HTML.

But I noticed there is a performance issue, CPU uses are increased by 20-30%.

Is there any alternative to login using C# and navigate another page to scrape the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I used [HTML Agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) in the past. I didn't see any high CPU usage. That could depend on what the scraping is doing, and how you've setup the tasks.

Comment: Using HTML Agility pack, Can I enter username and password then click on the login button to login and scrape the HTML table ( table have ajax paging).

Comment: Depending on how the website works, I would recommend figuring out how you log in, and log in using HTTP Requests, and then hitting the page once logged in. It's much simpler, and you can avoid potential bot checks like reCAPTCHA. I have not used HTML Agility pack for that before, so I cannot comment on that.